# Efficient Cumulative Product on Gorgonia Tensors in Go?

Tags: go, tensor, gonum

I'm trying to find the best way to fund the cumulative product of a Gorgonia Tensor. For example:

```
T := ts.New(ts.WithShape(3,4), ts.WithBacking(ts.Range(ts.Float32,1,13)))
    for row := 1; row < 3; row++ {
        for col :=0; col < 4; col++ {
            val1, _ := T.At(row-1, col).(float32)
            val2, _ := T.At(row, col).(float32)
            newVal := val1*val2
            T.SetAt(newVal, row, col)
        }
    }
```

I want the output to be:

```
[1   2    3    4  ]
[5   12   21   32 ]
[45  120  231  384]
```

This works, but for modest sized tensors (500x50), it takes 2500 microseconds seconds per iteration. I need it to be much faster. The numpy .cumprod() takes about 10-20 microseconds for a similar computation. Is there a more efficient way to code this?

I'm using tensors because I need to do matrix multiplication, and I want to use float32 for memory constraints. If necessary, I could switch it to gonum matrices, but I would rather not have to spend the extra memory if there is a way to do it with float32.

Comment: I suggest you write a benchmark and see what the bottleneck is.

Comment: It seems like most of the time is spent setting and accessing the tensor values, which is why I'm hoping someone knows a more efficient way to implement this.

Comment: That is to be expected. Does this tensor library you're using come with its own multiplication? Usually they are optimized beyond what you can do yourself. Worst case, if it has a way of letting to access a row maybe you can speed it up a bit by working with rows (or cols)